# Having issues with Echo PHP/JS

Tags: javascript, php

I hava an issue with my PHP/javascript code

I dont understand how to escape code it breaks my brain

```
echo "<button id='$date' onclick = 'document.getElementById('$date').style.display ='none'';>$date</button>";
```

anyone have an idea?

Everything after getElementById(' is not interpreted anymore

Comment: You've a quoting mess, try to pair the quotes correctly.

Comment: Corrected , thank you :) It works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correct the quotes.

```
echo "<button id=`$date` onclick = `document.getElementById('$date').style.display ='none'`;>$date</button>";
```

If button id is from php, you have to correct this too.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
echo "<button id='$date' onclick = \"document.getElementById('$date').style.display ='none'\";>$date</button>";
```